# Why low rep users edits end up in a review queue when they edit an answer of a highly active rep user

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits

Yesterday, I was reviewing a 35-minute-old edit of a user with 100+ rep points. The answer he was editing was a user who had 30k+ rep. In my opinion, that edit should not end up right away in a review queue. This edit contained changes to the OP's code inside the post, so I even couldn't approve it, because I didn't know it's correct.

**My proposal of solution:**

Stop stacking edits to the review queue right away. Add at least a 10-24 hour gap when an edit will end up in Review Queues/[Suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review), so the OP has a chance to review it first.

This solution will save reviewers time. The OP is the best person to review and approve his/her own post edits. Excuses that the OP is notified he/she can review approve edit is not enough. Many programmers read that kind of edits and skip after all.

**About 30k+ reputation I mentioned earlier:**

I still don't know how exactly Stack Overflow works. Approved suggested edits might have some second functionality. And it might be wrong if the editor gets approved by the OP user with 100 rep. I mean, he/she should not get same benefits as approved by suggested edits (assuming there are some benefits).

Comment: Edit queue is of finite size, so the held edit can't afford to sit there for a day or two. new infrastructure would be necessary. Many users don't check in often enough, if at all, to make the delay reasonable. If you're forced to skip, no worries. Many more reviewers, though still not enough, will be along and will have the expertise necessary to confirm or deny the edit as correct and useful to the community.

Comment: The rep of the participants is irrelevant. If the suggestion is good, approve it. If it is not, reject. If you don't know, skip.

Comment: FYI (in case you aren't aware) - down votes on meta also mean "this voter doesn't agree with implementing this suggestion"... so don't take them personally.

Comment: I generally support any change, like this one, that supports things being handled outside of the queues. Though... I wouldn't tie it to the post owner's rep.

Comment: I'm confused. You're just looking to increase the amount of time between the edit being suggested and handled by review queue? The post author is always the first notified that an edit was suggested on their post (they get a notification in their inbox) and have unilateral approval/rejection abilities. The suggested edit is pushed to the end of the queue so there's usually a fair amount of time for the post owner to handle the suggested edit if they wanted to do so.

Comment: Sure, delay it for 2 days, and if the queue is full when the delay is over "expire" it.

Comment: @HenryEcker Edit I was reviewing had 35m. Later I was spoken with PO, he was sleeping. Not everyone has notifications on. I personally check stack overflow few times in a day. And yes, I want to increase the amount of time that edit will end-up in rev queue.

Comment: @KevinB I don't exactly know how it works. I know that we can save reviewers time by letting PO decide first to approve or deny an edit suggestion.

Comment: effectively I was replying to henry ecker, what he's (correctly) stating is that the current way the review queues work effectively already do what you're suggesting by edits being reviewed in order of submission... meaning the post author is very much likely to be able to review it themselves if they're active. My point was, maybe if it entering the queue was delayed by 2 days, we'd solve several problems at once. No more "queue is full" rejections, and more edits get handled directly outside of the queue by people invested in the posts they're on.

Comment: eh, technically there'd still be queue is full rejections, but you'll only notice they occurred if you looked through your own suggested edits, which would be far less irritating i'd imagine than typing out an edit and it being rejected with noone being able to see it.

Comment: What is "PO"? Poster? That would normally be "[OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420)" ("original poster").

Comment: @PeterMortensen For me, its PO is "post owner"

Comment: Side note: as @Edward said tagging post that is essentially feature-request with "discussion" does not change a voting pattern. It potentially indicates that author did not want to make an effort to write proper proposal.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good to know I edited tag. You are the first one that point out what I did wrong with this post. Instead of just close voting to it.

Comment: "The answer he was editing was a user who had 30k+ rep. In my opinion, that edit should not end up right away in a review queue" I don't understand the reasoning. Why should it matter for reviewing an edit, if the person who wrote the original material has a high reputation? Aside from the fact that high-rep users are perfectly capable of writing garbage sometimes, it's just as easy to make a bad edit to good material as it is to make a bad edit to bad material. The reason for the queue is that we don't trust the editor fully yet. That's the **only** consideration.

Comment: "PO is "post owner"" - we don't "own" posts here. This is **not a discussion forum**, and questions and answers are licensed to the site under a Creative Commons BY-SA license and are free to edit by anyone. Subject, of course, to the reputation and queue restrictions.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You might have right about post owner. The words "post owner" is just always first on my mind. The words "Original Poster" don't fit for me, so I won't be able to remember it fast. Better would be PC "Post Creator".

Comment: And about 30k+ rep. Well, he probably is able to edit any questions or answer without need to review his edits by others. Approving reviews might have another purpose, to check are someone is not trolling. 400 rep user have no ability to approve anything.

Answer (score 5):

My take on this is allowing the suggested edit to exist outside of the queue for two days, ignoring the reputation of the post owner requirement you suggested, would be a way of removing some of pressure on the suggested edits queue by only putting suggested edits into the queue if they haven't been approved/rejected outside of the queue after two days.

However... all we'd really be doing with such a change is hiding new edits from the suggested edit queue, meaning limiting the number of people the suggested edit is visible to in the first 2 days and making it take longer to get approved. I like the thought process, but the reality of it doesn't *really* make for a better system. It's solving the wrong problem.

Comment: This identifies the problem suggested solution solves - how to nicely limit number of suggested edits to 5 per 2 days... Unfortunately, it also will get confusing behavior when one directly see that post or tries to edit it again...

Answer (score -10):

The quick fix for that would be to just edit the Stack Overflow front end and get 10-24 hours old edits in the Review queues / Suggested Edits.

The way I would do that is using the backend when an edit is posted and let a server check if the PO (Post owner) is an active user and decide if the edit should end up in a Review queue right away or get a timeout, so the PO can approve the edit.

Comment: Just a Remark, but I don't think that proposing Modifications to the SO "*Front End*" + "*Back End*" will be a "*quick fix*"... (... or you should join the Dev Team for SO...!) // [Translation: "*are*" = "if"...]

Comment: @chivracq Well I prefer NoSQL databases and that kind of change in NoSQL would be just creating new Micro Service with a function or for example Firebase Function or Google Cloud Function. And change a few lines of code in the front-end.

Comment: Nope..., no 'NoSQL' / 'Firebase' / 'Google Cloud' I'm afraid in the [Architecture used by SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10370/642998)... // And well, what I meant (a bit ironically) about "*quick fix*", is that many Feature Requests were proposed/asked more than 10 years ago, ... and still haven't been implemented...